# If statement inside a for loop prints all values as true if any are - bash

Tags: git, bash

I want to find a git project containing the project name inputed and auto cd into it. It should be a simple bash function but it behaves strangely.

```
project() {
    target=$1"/.git"
    for string in "$(find ~ -name .git -type d -prune)"
    do
        if [[ $string == *"${target}" ]]
        then
            echo $string
        else
            echo 2
        fi
    done
    # cd "$HOME/Work/$1/src"
}
```

If I were to echo all the projects found (the string values), it properly prints out all of the projects. Also, target is also a valid string. The expected result should be echoing of the correct path once, and all other values to be 2.

The problem appears when the code matches `target` as being part of the `string`. In that case it prints out ALL projects, instead of the wanted one. If the pattern doesn't match any projects, the code will print the value `2` ONCE. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using zsh but I really don't know.

Comment: Your quotes are making the entire result of `find` be a single string, so if the string matches your pattern the entire thing is printed.  Is there a reason not to do the string matching as part of the `find` command, or do you really need the non-matching ones as well?  word splitting is going to cause a lot of trouble for you with trying to process the files the way you're doing it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- The shell does not perform word splitting on an expression enclosed within double-quotes, so `"$(find ...)"` in a loop context is a single word
- Even if you remove those double-quotes, the results of `find` will be subject to word splitting, and that makes it not suitable to use in a `for` loop
- Instead of using `[[ ... == ... ]]` to match patterns on the result of `find`, it would be better to use `find` itself to match patterns, that's what the tool is designed for
- Why `echo 2`, and why `echo` in a loop? It seems you want to use the result of this function with `cd`, and that won't go well with multiple outputs
- Lastly, and this is just a nitpick, the quoting here is not a problem, but it's weird: `target=$1"/.git"`. You don't actually need the quotes here, this would be just fine: `target=$1/.git`. If you were using `$1/.git` in a command line argument, it's the `$1` the most important to quote, as `.git` has certainly no special characters in it. Long story short, you should write `"$1"/.git` or `"$1/.git"`.

Here's one way to fix the above issues:

```
project() {
    local path
    while IFS= read -rd '' path; do
        echo "$path"
        return 0
    done < <(find ~ -type d -path "**/$1/.git" -print0)
    echo "project not found: $1" >&2
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind a few improvements. The previous version would always print the error message. Switching from `find | while` to `while < <(find)` eliminates the subshell allowing the loop to `return`. `IFS=` and `-print0` make the code even safer in the presence of really weird file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do much of what this function does using the `CDPATH` variable. For example,

```
$ CDPATH=$HOME/Work
$ cd project/src
$ pwd
/home/jyslar/Work/project/src
```

Incorporating this into your function,

```
project () {
    local CDPATH="$HOME/Work"
    cd "$1/src"
}
```

There is no explicit check for a `.git` directory, but it seems reasonable to assume that the contents of `$HOME/Work` are all Git repositories, or that at least it's not worth complicating the definition of `project` to avoid false positives (e.g., if `$HOME/Work/$1/src` is a directory without `$1` actually being a Git repository).

---

Wait, you ask: why do I need `CDPATH`? Couldn't I just define

```
project () { cd "$HOME/Work/$1/src"; }
```

Yes, you could. I suppose my point was that you don't even need a function. Just add

```
CDPATH=$HOME/Work
```

to your `.bashrc`; then `cd project-omega/src` will automatically take you to `$HOME/Work/project-omega/src` if `project-omega` doesn't happen to exist in the current working directory.

Like `PATH`, `CDPATH` can contain a colon-separated list of directories, for example:

```
CDPATH=$HOME/Work:$HOME/Fun:$HOME/Experimental
```

Comment: I had a setup like that before, but because of some complicated projects that have submodules, I wanted something little more elegant